# ZF6 Foundation Sticky don't work out of the box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky, zurb-foundation-6

https://jsfiddle.net/ffzgmky7/1/

Version 6.2 
Trying to implement Foundation 6's Sticky Menu, exactly as stated on the documentation but I can't init it.  is there something obvious that I miss?

```
<div style="height:9999999px">
    <div style="width:100%" data-sticky-container>
        <div class="title-bar" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%" data-top-anchor="1" data-btm-anchor="content:bottom">
        <div class="title-bar-left">EXAMPLE</div>
        <div class="title-bar-right">STICKY</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css') }}" type="text/css">

<script src="{{ url('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('js/script.js') }}"></script>
<!-- $(document).foundation(); in js/script.js  -->
```

All the JS is right before `</body>`, I try put it in the head, but I don't think it change anything.

Comment: You need to call `$(document).foundation()`

Comment: I did as stated in the jsfiddle, I will add it to code just for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Zurb Foundation 6 documentation isn't exactly helpful**, and, your fiddle is working against you, slightly.

Here is a sticky title bar based on your code above. If you paste that directly into your fiddle html it will work. If you remove the `<script>$(document).foundation();</script>` from the bottom of the html and put `$(document).foundation();` in the fiddle's javascript container, it will not. Also, notice the **height** in the title bar. Without the height and when scrolling back to top, the title bar shrinks.

You'll notice that the  `data-top-anchor="1"` and `data-btm-anchor="content:bottom"` have both been removed. Either appear to ok to have in there, but if you add them both (as in the documentation), it doesn't work properly.

```
<div style="height:9999999px">
  <div data-sticky-container>
        <div class="title-bar" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%;height:45px;" >
            <div class="title-bar-left">EXAMPLE</div>
            <div class="title-bar-right">STICKY</div>
        </div>
  </div>

  <h3 class='text-center'>Foo Sticky, no sticky.</h3>
  <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, temporibus a reprehenderit, adipisci expedita nam odio neque alias eligendi, consectetur sapiente dicta tenetur perspiciatis. Aspernatur modi provident obcaecati impedit dignissimos.
  </p>
</div>
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
```

Hopefully this can get you started.

Here is the Zurb Foundation 6 documentation if you want to see an example of how not to do it:  http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html#sticky-navigation

Comment: this makes me really want to switch to bootstrap, that I had resisted for years.

Comment: Keep your head up. It appears to work pretty good (when you get it right) and the documentation is bound to improve. If it doesn't, we'll get it all figured out here. :)

Comment: Yeah.... Off canvas seems broken too... If used with sticky.  Sadly foundation is only as good as the grid.